# Compiling Multi file C++ program

Tags: c++, compilation

I need some help in understanding following compilation for C++.
Following are the 3 files,

Employee.h

```
class Employee{
private:
std::string m_empName = "DEFAULT_NAME";
int         m_age     = -99;
long        m_num     = 0l;

public:
Employee(std::string p_empName, int p_age, long p_num);
};
```

Employee.cpp

```
#include"Employee.h"

Employee::Employee(std::string p_empName = "DEFAULT_CONST_NAME", int p_age = -98, long p_num = 0):
m_empName{p_empName},m_age{p_age},m_num{p_num}{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include"Employee.h"
int main(){
Employee e1;
return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code I get following Compilation error,

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:14: error: no matching function for call to 
‘Employee::Employee()’
 Employee e1;
```

But If I move all the code from main.cpp to Employee.cpp (and delete main.cpp) and compile I don't get these compilation error.

Can someone please help to understand how this compilation/ linking is working here.

Thanks.

Comment: `Employee`'s constructor is declared to take three parameters, not zero. The default arguments should go into the declaration, not the definition.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That should be made into an answer....

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments should be visible to callers, otherwise they wouldn't be able to use them. Things that should be visible to others go in header files.

The following should go in the .h file:

```
Employee(std::string p_empName = "DEFAULT_CONST_NAME",
    int p_age = -98,
    long p_num = 0);
```

And this should go in the .cpp file:

```
Employee::Employee(std::string p_empName, 
    int p_age, 
    long p_num) :
```